# Aws Elasticsearch access policy to allow Https Get requests & block all other requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to allow HTTP get requests to my AWS Elasticsearch domain from anyone. And to restrict all other requests like CREATE, DELETE to the IAM user only. I tried using this below policy and was able to successfully create, delete indices by signing requests with my user credentials (using aws-es-proxy tool). But HTTP requests to the domain from public computers are failing.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:356298639800:domain/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::356298639800:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:356298639800:domain/myusername/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Public HTTP requests to the ES domain are failing with error "Anonymous is not authorized".
[Account ID mentioned above is a dummy number]

Comment: was the domain created in VPC or with public access?

Comment: I've chosen "Allow or deny access to one or more AWS accounts or IAM users" option as access policy. And then used the above mentioned access policy.

Comment: i was asking about the domain configuration was it created in with  [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html)  or public access ?

Comment: Well, it was with public access.

Comment: try including ES name after domain in Resource (...:domain/<ES-name/*).

You can add an nginx in front and only allow GET requests in it as a workaround.